# Grayed out screen Overlays opening page in the login form (such as Mozilla Alert)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a login form when the enter button is clicked I want the page to be gray background

But the code that I wrote is a problem and it is their entry forms will also be gray (such as Mozilla firefox Alert)

[**Jsffidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rRvVF/1/)

```
    <div class="wrap"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn-login btn btn-lg ">
        Login
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="form-signin">
   <p>Login</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="fitsname">First Name</label>
                    <input id="fitsname" class="form-control" type="text"/>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="lastname" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be because you specified the form input to have `background: rgba(59, 255, 2, 0.5);` which means that the opacity of the div is 0.5. This means the background will show through!

Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRvVF/4/)

If you want the same color as you have in your example, just choose an appropriate RBG color and input that into the `background: rgba(59, 255, 2, 1.0);`